# How to dynamically set your apps' Base priority to 31?

Tags: c++, c, windows, api, visual-studio-2005

I have the following problem - I want to set my C++ application's [Base priority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685100%28VS.85%29.aspx) to 31 if that is possible or at least set its current priority to 31.

So I need a simple example like

1. `set priority to 31;`
2. `for (i=0;i<100000;++i) { printf("hello world"); }`
3. set priority to 8 or keep 31 if possible

Comment: A base priority of `31` means `THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL` under `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS`. *Nothing* but your app will be able to run on the machine. Are you positively, absolutely sure you really want to do that?

Comment: Isn't this just `SetProcessClass(GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);` and `SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);`? That's more or less straight out of the examples linked from the page you linked.

Comment: And do you want to change your `C++` application's Base priority with a `C` program?

Comment: You really **do not** want to do this.

Comment: @all yes - I do... in educational purposes only=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set your priority class to the realtime priority class, you need to be running with elevated privileges (as an admin).

As others have asked, are you SURE you want to do this?  If you set your priority that high, it will lock out all other processing on the system (even the mouse will stop working).

One option that allows you to perform operations without being preempted that's somewhat more system friendly (but only available on Vista and beyond) is to use the [Multimedia Class Scheduler Service (MMCSS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684247%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Sory - _"Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP/2000:  MMCSS is not available."_ and I am working with XP sp3 using vs2005